Microsoft Bot Framework with MS Teams - Expected or unexpected exceptions
I am facing an issue concerning an exception which is appearing in the output window of my Visual Studio during a debugging session of my chatbot (Bot Emulator, Microsoft BotFramework).
At first glance, this exception occurs after a first turn with the bot, once some threads exited and completed their execution.
The triggering of these exceptions doesn't affect the proper functioning of my application, but this behavior concerns me a bit.
Here is what I see (without breaking when IOException thrown):

Here is what I see (with breaking when IOException thrown):
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response headers after 2.2473ms - 200
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler: Information: End processing HTTP request after 14.5316ms - 200
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executed action ChatBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (ChatBot) in 1209.2791ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint 'ChatBot.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (ChatBot)'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:3978/api/messages application/json 710 - 200 - - 1237.6957ms
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (8392) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (11000) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (7724) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (6896) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (4820) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (17184) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (1328) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '[Thread Destroyed]' (15716) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Sockets.dll
Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'. 


Does someone knows if this behavior could be considered as normal or if I should investigate further?
Thank you for your feedback.
Regards,
Fred

It sounds like you're encountering a System.IO.IOException in System.Net.Sockets.dll during your debugging session with the Bot Emulator in Microsoft BotFramework. This exception typically occurs when there is an issue with the transport connection, often due to a thread exit or an application request.
From the logs you provided, it seems that the exception is thrown after several threads have exited, but it doesn't affect the proper functioning of your application. This behaviour can be concerning, but it might not necessarily indicate a critical issue.
